# Javamail error: SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 too many connections from your IP (rate controlled)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I have a Spring 4.1.1 web application in which the user can set some scheduled tasks. When these tasks complete the administrator will receive an automatic email sent with the SMTP method.

For the email I use the jars: javax.mail-api-1.5.2.jar and mail-1.5.0-b01.jar

The email are sent correctly at first, but when the frequency of the tasks goes up eventually I start to get the following exception and all subsequent emails fails. I can send about 30 emails in a 10 minutes window.

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 too many connections from your IP (rate controlled)

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1118)
at com.synaptic.email.MessageMail.sendMessage(MessageMail.java:152)
at com.synaptic.email.EmailManagerImpl.sendGeneralEmail(EmailManagerImpl.java:423)
```

The code snippet from which I send the emails is:

```
    public void sendMessage(Brand brand, String timeout) throws MessagingException
{
    try {
        // Prepare message
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", timeout);
        props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", timeout);
        props.put("mail.smtp.writetimeout", timeout);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", Integer.parseInt(brand.getBrandProperties().getEmailPort()));

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        message = new MimeMessage(session);
        createMessage();

        if (brand.getBrandProperties().getEmailUsername().isEmpty() && brand.getBrandProperties().getEmailPassword().isEmpty()) {
            // Send email message to SMTP server without auth
            Transport.send(message);
        } else {
            // Send message with auth
            Transport.send(message,brand.getBrandProperties().getEmailUsername(),brand.getBrandProperties().getEmailPassword());
        }
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.error("Failed to send email message.", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

From the javamail documentation and source code seems clear that the transport connection are closed on a finally statement, so no connection should be hanging open, but still I hit this exception.

I checked online but I can't find a way to increase this limit.

Am I doing something wrong sending the message? is there a way to monitor the email connections? or is an email server issue?

Comment: I think that you have too many connections from your IP restriction....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is telling you that you're making too many connections in too short a time.  It's rate-limiting you to prevent you from abusing the server.  You may need to pay for a higher quality of service to be allowed to send more messages.  Contact your ISP for details.

BTW, you say you're using javax.mail-api-1.5.2.jar and mail-1.5.0-b01.jar.  You should not mix and match versions like that.  You only need one jar file - the javax.mail-1.5.2.jar file.  You can get it on the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: He could try using an explicit Transport object and keeping it open for longer, say a minute or two, to send multiple emails per connection. As he's sending 3 emails/minute that will multiple the number of emails he can send. Once he starts getting 450 he will still just have to stop of course.

Comment: It depends on how frequently the messages are being sent.  The connection might just timeout between uses.  Or the application could queue up a bunch of notifications and only send them every 10 minutes, using one connection.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I'll try to contact the ISP provider on Monday and perhaps to batch the emails. Regarding the jars, for some reasons I get a class not found exception when I use javax.mail-api-1.5.2.jar alone, that's why I included the other jar, but perhaps they're are in conflict with each other. I'll try that option too.

Comment: The javax.mail-api jar file only has the standard JavaMail classes to compile against; it doesn't have everything you need to run an application.